# How to convert a custom cell to value with the words in custom in excel

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

My cell has custom (  #,##0 "PCS"   ) and true value is just a number but i want to convert it to real value which is combined number and "PCS" for copying purpose. I have tried many idea but still not found the solution for this. please help if there're any function, script or code to do this. truly need your all help. Thank youu

Expected to check all sheet if any custom like that and change to real value.

Comment: `Worksheets(...).Range(...).Value = Worksheets(...).Range(...).Text` may work

Answer (score 1):

A cell's `NumberFormat` dictates its *string representation* - but doesn't affect its *value*.

In order to make the number-formatted string representation the value itself, you can assign the cell's `Value` to its `Text` property:

```
theCell.Value = theCell.Text
```